# Perform an action after the animation has finished

Tags: ios, animation, switch-statement, wait

I'm performing an animation on an image where I rotate it 180 degrees.

Then I have inserted a code to switch to another view.

However, the app is switching views before the animation ends.

How can I wait for the animation to finish in order to switch view afterwards?

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    CABasicAnimation *imageRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];

    imageRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    imageRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((180*M_PI)/ 180)];

    imageRotation.duration = 1.5;
    imageRotation.repeatCount = 1;

    imageRotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    imageRotation.autoreverses=NO;
    imageRotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    [_image.layer addAnimation:imageRotation forKey:@"imageRotation"];

    // Switching Views
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ToGalleryVCSegue" sender: self];

}
```

Comment: I've found the answer to it from another post.

it uses the following:

[self performSelector:@selector(metohodToPushView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];

Comment: That is not a very good way to achieve this.  Using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: is a hack.  See the answer about animateWithDuration:animations:completion:.

Comment: ... and `CGAffineTransformRotate` which you can use to rotate the `transform` property of the view.

Answer (score 5):

Use UIView's animateWithDuration:animations:completion: method.  Put your call to performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: in the completion block.  eg:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                 animations:^{
        // put your animation code here, eg:
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        self.imageView.transform = transform;
    }
                 completion:^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ToGalleryVCSegue" sender: self];
    }];
```

Comment: I've tried it but it's not waiting for 1.5 seconds. It's directly switching the views.
I added my whole animation code as in my first post until the switching views.

Comment: Are you adding the CABasicAnimation code inside there?  That shouldn't be necessary and it might even interfere with animateWithDuration.  See the updated code in the example I gave for how to do a rotation transformation with animateWithDuration.