# removeFromSuperlayer not removing layer

Tags: ios7, caanimation, cashapelayer

I am writing code that will allow the user to temporarily highlight a section of an image. In my view class, I used touchesBegan, touchesMoved and, touchesEnded to pick up a UIBezierPath from the screen.  I added the path to a layer, stroked the path and used a animation to fade the opacity of the layer from 1 to 0.  The two NSLog statements confirm that the layer is added to the sublayer array

```
drawVanishingPath
{
    NSLog(@"There were %d sublayers before the path was added",[self.layer.sublayers count]);
    disappearingLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    disappearingLayer.strokeColor = self.strokeColor.CGColor;
    disappearingLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    disappearingLayer.lineWidth = [self.strokeSize floatValue];
    disappearingLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    [self.layer addSublayer:disappearingLayer];
    [disappearingLayer addAnimation:fadeAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
    [fadeAnimation setValue:disappearingLayer forKey:@"parentLayer"];
    disappearingLayer.opacity = 0.0;
    NSLog(@"There are %d sublayers after adding the path",[self.layer.sublayers count]);
}
```

Based on the answer to another question on stack overflow ([How to remove a layer when its animation completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688440/how-to-remove-a-layer-when-its-animation-completes)) I set the delegate for the animation and implemented animationDidStop: finished: as shown below.  I added two NSLog statements to confirm that the layer was removed from the layer array.

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"There were %d sublayers",[self.layer.sublayers count]);
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [animation valueForKey:@"parentLayer"];
    [layer removeAllAnimations];
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    NSLog(@"There are now %d sublayers",[self.layer.sublayers count]);
}
```

When the program runs, the layer is added and the layer count is incremented as expected, but the layer count does not decrement in animationDidStop: finished:.  Since the layers are not removed, the program will have many unneeded layers in the program.  These could cause problems later on.

I believe I am misunderstanding something, but I am not sure what is wrong.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[How to remove a layer when its animation completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688440/how-to-remove-a-layer-when-its-animation-completes)

Comment: By the way, this was quite a well-posed question (upvoted for that). You showed all and only the essential code, and you had done most of the logging so as to be certain of what was happening (though there was one important bit of logging you didn't do, which would have revealed the source of the problem). You show your reasoning clearly and concisely, and the question itself is clear. And you've done your homework before posting. Would that all questions were like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track! The problem is these lines:

```
[disappearingLayer addAnimation:fadeAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
[fadeAnimation setValue:disappearingLayer forKey:@"parentLayer"];
```

They are in the wrong order! Reverse their order and all will be well.

The reason: you can't modify the animation after adding it to a layer. Well, you can, but it does no good: *the animation has been copied*, so what you're modifying is now not the animation you added.

Thus, you were never setting the animation's `parentLayer` key. So in the delegate method, that key was nil and no layer was being removed.

As a test, I ran this simplified version of your code, and it worked as expected:

```
- (void)drawVanishingPath {
    NSLog(@"There were %d sublayers before the path was added",[self.layer.sublayers count]);
    CAShapeLayer* disappearingLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    disappearingLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    disappearingLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    disappearingLayer.lineWidth = 5;
    disappearingLayer.path = _path;
    [self.layer addSublayer:disappearingLayer];

    CABasicAnimation* fadeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeAnimation.toValue = @0;
    fadeAnimation.duration = 2;
    fadeAnimation.delegate = self;
    [fadeAnimation setValue:disappearingLayer forKey:@"parentLayer"];
    [disappearingLayer addAnimation:fadeAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
    NSLog(@"There are %d sublayers after adding the path",[self.layer.sublayers count]);
}

-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"There were %d sublayers",[self.layer.sublayers count]);
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [animation valueForKey:@"parentLayer"];
    [layer removeAllAnimations];
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    NSLog(@"There are now %d sublayers",[self.layer.sublayers count]);
}
```

The log reads:

```
2014-05-03 17:23:21.204 PathTest[5100:60b] There were 0 sublayers before the path was added
2014-05-03 17:23:21.209 PathTest[5100:60b] There are 1 sublayers after adding the path
2014-05-03 17:23:23.210 PathTest[5100:60b] There were 1 sublayers
2014-05-03 17:23:23.211 PathTest[5100:60b] There are now 0 sublayers
```

Comment: But your animation is not going to run (as an animation) if you set the opacity to 0 directly afterwards as you're doing in your code. You'll have to fix that eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It is running correctly now.  You are also correct about the opacity issue.  I am also setting this somewhere else and you pointed out that the line is not needed.